# Ruby GUI blocks command line

Tags: ruby, multithreading, user-interface, gtk3

I created an iteractive commandline interpreter for a language. Now I want to extend it with a GUI to display some data of the interpreter.

So I want a user to be able to type something in my interpreter, while the GUI is running.
The problem is: Whenever I start the window, the commandline interpreter does not work anymore.
By "not work" I mean, I can still type something, but the interpreter will only interpret the input, when the window has been closed.

```
repl_thread = Thread.new{ repl() }
gui_thread = Thread.new{ InterpreterGUI.launch() }

repl_thread.join
gui_thread.join
```

I created two threads. One is running the GUI and the other is running the REP-Loop, where the user can type in the language.
Does anybody have an idea why the behavior is like this?

In case it is important: I'm creating the GUI using GTK3.

Comment: Just a guess, but did you also use Gtk for the command line interpreter? Then it is most likely the case that both windows are running on the same `GLib` main thread. But do better than guessing sharing more code would necessary.

Comment: No the CLI is just a normal linux terminal. I start the Interpreter with `ruby interpreter.rb`. Then I can type text in this terminal.

Comment: Interesting, In that case I also don't really have a clue.. It sounds like something is block your CLI thread, but it seems to me that it shouldn't be possible assuming the joins are reached...